# Rendering on Firefox vs Chrome/Safari/Opera

Tags: html, css, firefox, rendering

I'm trying to solve my issue of the way [MY PAGE](https://www.realtimehockey.net/camps.html) renders on Firefox vs Chrome/Safari/Opera.  **My question**: Should I be adding something to the CSS that I am missing?  I have tried adding a `line-height: 100%` and `line-height: normal` to no avail.  Everything looks fine on the latter 3:[image: Camp Screenshot Chrome]

When I pull the page up on Firefox, things become distorted.  Specifically the social share icons and borders:
[image: Camp Screenshot Firefox]

I am using the following code to insert the script:

CSS

```
<style>
div.scroll {
max-height: 1250px;
overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="scroll">
<script src="//dashboard.time.ly/js/embed.js" data-
src="https://events.time.ly/hye2ww2" id="timely_script" class="timely-
script"></script>
</div>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible solution: in this code: `.timely-stream:not(.timely-agenda) .timely-event { height: 92px !important; }` ... maybe use `min-height` instead...

Comment: @Michael_B are you saying use "min-height" instead of "max-height" in the CSS?

Comment: I'm saying in that rule that I posted, switch the `height` to `min-height`. That may be a good place to start troubleshooting.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your page. I mean, what's with all the `<!DOCTYPE html>`s? Things like that. Different browsers have different error handling routines, so It's quite likely that those account for at least some of the differences.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for your input.  I use Zoho Sites to build my site so, in no means am I an adept at this.  This being said, as I'm sure you are aware, each page is comprised of several different "widgets" with each containing separate code, therefore each element is initiated with <!DOCTYPE html>.  Perhaps, I don't need them all.  I'm trying to learn and assumed I needed to start each individual snippet this way.  Should I try eliminating the <!DOCTYPE html>?  Could this solve the Firefox issue?  Thanks again.